# Certain web icons do not appear in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, webfonts

I made some webicons in the Private Use Area from E000-E900.

In my HTML I have tried placing them in `<i>`:

```
        <i class="wikicon wikicon-pencil"></i>
```

as well as `<span>`:

```
        <span class="wikicon wikicon-pencil"></span>
```

while in CSS:

```
       .wikicon-pencil:before {
        content: "\e800";
       }
```

Neither `<i>` nor `<span>` worked. With other icons though, it would work, it only happens to what seems like the unfortunate half of the icon set.

I tried them on Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. The only way it would work is when I specify the unicode entity, but that's not ideal at all.

```
        <i class="wikicon">&#xe000;</i>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `i` tag is used to write italic text: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-I

Comment: Try to upload the font (i assume you're using a icon-font set) again?
@adripanico, the `i` tag is common used for icon display purposes.

Comment: Are you trying to use a special font that is not part of most font packages?

Comment: @leigro, yes I'm trying to use a font that I just created.

Comment: @davey, I'm trying them locally and it hasn't worked either.

Comment: Any errors in the console of your firebug / developer tools?

Comment: @davey no errors at all :/

Comment: @adrinpanico : the `i` tag isn't just for italics under HTML5 - https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in private Unicode mapping, so following reply will explain you, you have to change mapping.

[How to embed Unicode Supplementary Private Use characters in CSS generated content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914584/how-to-embed-unicode-supplementary-private-use-characters-in-css-generated-conte)

Hope this clarify all.

Comment: Thanks KamalPanhwar, I mapped them to other PUA areas and still did not work. However, when I mapped it to any Latin chars, it worked. But that's not a practical solution due to many reasons. I'll keep waiting to see what's actually wrong with this..!

Comment: It mean it was a problem of mapping, you have to change mapping and I don't see any issue with changing mapping for icons! as font will be used in only specific font file with css. There is nothing wrong it is how it works. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more codes how you are using? As css coding is not present in question.

As I am using in following way in my css

```
.icon-file-alt:before {
  content: "\f016";
}
```

and on my html

```
<i class='icon-file-alt'></i>
```

I have also special fonts added in website which is basically icons.

Comment: It looks about the same with what I'm using, except I have an additional .wikicon rule in my css. You can view them here http://bit.ly/1jnnJmY

Comment: I have checked your font file and surprise it does not have any charter. Although i don't have any good font editor but I tried to open on mac and it showed one W charter in file, and than I used another software fontbook it also show no character in your font file. So probably reason is no character in your font file.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, they are located within PUA from E000-E900. That's why you're only seeing W.